# Json (jiffy) support for ejabberd 2.1.11

Tags: json, ejabberd, jiffy

I am using ejabberd 2.1.11 and willing to add support for json parsing using [jiffy](https://github.com/davisp/jiffy)

I did install erlang-jiffy and it works on erlang shell, but not within ejabberd modules. Is there any way we can configure it work with ejabberd?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the path to the jiffy beam file set up when you start ejabberd so that you can use them.
Check erl -pa option.

Comment: Michkael, thanks a lot for your response.
can you please elaborate a bit more, I did copied compiled files in the ejabberd ebin + priv directory, but it was not working for me.

Comment: Well, as you do not provide any information exact fact that it does not work from inside ejabberd, it is hard to tell. My guess was that you had error undef (meaning module not found)

Comment: Mickael, Actually, I did add as a module but there was a problem that it was showing undef fucntion (not for the main function decode but for another internal function). So finally I switched to another library (mochijso2) edited a bit to use a module and its working fine with ejabberd 2.1.11  Thank You